# nutch V2 (with solr) deleting documents

Tags: solr, nutch

So I'm using nutch V2 to index my website.
But pages that no longer exist (I'm indexing a CMS, so pages can be removed) are not removed from the SOLR index.

I have tried to set: `db.update.purge.404=true` in my `nutch-default.xml` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

For nutch V1 I can see that the commandline parameter *"-deleteGone"* exists, but from the documentation I can only guess that it's removed in V2.

So my question is: how do I configure nutch V2 to remove non existent urls?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `db.update.purge.404=true` in `nutch-site.xml`, not in `nutch-default.xml`